# Redirecting file descriptor 3 with tee

Tags: bash, shell, unix, redirect, tee

I wrote this script some months ago, and now rereading it, I'm unable to decipher what I meant by this line:

```
sudo rsync -xPRSaz --rsync-path='sudo rsync' maeve@macbook:/ macbook/ 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee macbook.log
```

I can't find any special treatment of file descriptor 3 for `sudo`, `rsync` or `tee`. After the redirects I'm currently guessing this is the situation:

```
now fd points to old fd
     0    -->         0
     1    -->         2
     2    -->         1
     3    -->         1
```

- Are these redirects applied to `sudo`, or to `rsync`, and to what end?
- Is file descriptor 3 being left unclosed or hanging in any "bad" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right. It's a rather nifty trick to swap standard output and standard error. To answer your questions:

- these redirections are captured by the shell so they apply to that portion of the pipeline (which is `sudo`). The `sudo` process itself will detect all the arguments and pass them along to its subcommand (`rsync`) but the redirections have been captured and acted upon before that point: `sudo` never sees them.
- File handle 3 is not left hanging. It will be closed when the process ends.

Comment: Is it ever necessary, or possible, to close fd 3 prior to sudo executing? I've heard of a few programs that can be passed opened streams this way.

Comment: Not usually necessary, since processes shouldn't care what file descriptors are already open. There is a way to _move_ a file descriptor in `bash` (rather than duplicate it) which closes the original. So you could possibly use that get file handle 3 closed. I've never tried it (since I've never had a need) but look for "Moving file descriptors" in the `bash` manpage.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the dangling file descriptor `3` can be closed with `3>&-`, here's the full line with that included:

```
sudo rsync -xPRSaz --rsync-path='sudo rsync' maeve@macbook:/ macbook/ 3>&1 1>&2 \
2>&3 3>&- | tee macbook.log
```